# Getting Java Filesystem-Folder onchange event (Like Dropbox)

Tags: java, file, events, filesystems, onchange

I want to sync a folder like Dropbox. If in my Folder is changed a file or a folder, I want to get an Event, which starts my synchronisation Class. How can I get such an Event without scanning this folder by an Intervall?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options. You can either reinvent the wheel as Arpit suggested or you can also use the [WatchService API.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

You can find a WatchService tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Comment: WoW! its not my ques. but i think i should learn it. thanks for the link.+1

Answer (score 0):

Some start for you:

get the list of all files : `yourdir.listFiles()`

now for each file in filelist:
     `file.getLastModified()`

if it is equal to current time or differ from `lastSynctime`(you need to maintain it in your sync class)  then sync it.

Comment: Yes this is my actual version, but there I have to look through thousands of files, is this not time-consuming?

Comment: its not! because not all are going to modified at same time:)